# Debugger for C++ eclipse gives the following error. 'Launching program name' has encountered a ... Error while launching command: gdb --version

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb, mingw

I've always worked around the debugger issue, but now it has gotten too annoying. I'm working on more complex programs and can't anywhere if I cant debug my programs. Has any one else been able to fix this issue in eclipse? It works for java, but not more my C++ plugin from minGW

Debbugger for C++ eclipse gives the following error. 'Launching  program name' has encountered a problem. Error while launching command: gdb --version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows and have MinGW installed, you only need to locate the gdb executable in the MinGW bin folder. This can be done on the "Main" tab in the "Debugger" configuration of Eclipse:

[image: gdb configuration of eclipse]