# Why does gdb version 7.8.1 fail with eclipse for c++ and go?

Tags: eclipse, gdb, goclipse

I've install gdb on my mac and successfully gotten it to run from the command line and from LiteIDE. However, when I run it under Eclipse (Goclipse and C++ programs), I get the error:

Error with command: gdb --version
Cannot run program "gdb": Unknown reason

I have the latest version of gdb installed and I believe the path is correct.

I've tried modifying the gdb configuration in the C settings, but it had no effect.

Is there a problem finding the gdb executable or is it actually having trouble finding the executable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082234/mac-c-eclipse-cannot-debug-error-while-launching-command-gdb-version is of no help?

Comment: I saw that post and tried it without success yesterday. Today, it makes gdb run. Perhaps it was the update I did in between.

The bad news is that the debugger is very buggy. I'll probably switch to LiteIDE. Early indications are the debugger works better there.

Answer (score 0):

From the Goclipse User Guide:

*The GDB that is included with OS X doesn't work properly. You'll need to install the latest GDB from Homebrew. See [this article](http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/) for details. Or alternatively, [this Stack Oveflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162757/how-to-install-gdb-debugger-in-mac-osx-el-capitan), which might be more up-to-date.*