# Error with command: gdb --version

Tags: gdb, command, version

I am trying to debug my c++ program on my macbook pro. I just downloaded eclipse. When I try to debug my program it gives me the above error. What can I do to step-through my code and make this work?

Comment: Hmm... the error doesn't specify what happened :( May be... do you have gdb installed?

Comment: Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082234/mac-c-eclipse-cannot-debug-error-while-launching-command-gdb-version) looks related